# Ansible 2.3: single regular expression for replacing multi lines in a file

Tags: python, regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

Trying to find out regular expression to replace the below multi lines in a file

My destination file to update

```
# enable the encryption , to be used .
 ssh_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    algorithm: tls
```

my task definition

```
   - replace:
       path: /etc/config/
       regexp: '^(ssh_encryption_options:
     enabled: false)$'
       replace: '^(ssh_encryption_options:
     enabled: true)$'
     become: true
```

expected output in the file

```
ssh_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    optional: false
    algorithm: tls
```

But ansible is not able to find the multi lines in that file to replace , given in regex.I am sure some one out there had tried this scenario before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace `/etc/config/` with a path to the file you want to change;
2. Pay attention to whitespace (either add it explicitly or use `\s` for matching);
3. Use `\n` to match a newline;
4. Use capture group to simplify the replacement value.

---

```
- replace:
    path: /etc/config/_file_
    regexp: '^( ssh_encryption_options:\n\s*enabled: )false$'
    replace: '\1true'
  become: true
```

Comment: '^(ssh_encryption_options:\n\s*enabled: )false$'    removing space before ssh in regex ,worked perfect.Information really helped me.